# multidimensional array into table in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, html-table

I hope you can help me to finish my assignment. I still new with PHP language. I have a case like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: left;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$ub = array(
    array(
        "Fakultas Ilmu Komputer",
        array(
            "Jurusan Teknik Informatika",
            array(
                "Prodi Teknik Informatika",
                "Prodi Teknik Komputer",
                "Prodi Magister Ilmu Komputer"
            )
        ),
        array(
            "Jurusan Sistem Informasi",
            array(
                "Prodi Sistem Informasi",
                "Prodi Teknologi Informasi",
                "Prodi Pendidikan Teknologi Informasi"
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        "Fakultas Kedokteran",
        array(
            "Jurusan Kedokteran",
            array(
                "Prodi Pendidikan Dokter"
            )
        ),
        array(
            "Jurusan Keperawatan dan Gizi",
            array(
                "Prodi Ilmu Keperawatan",
                "Prodi Ilmu Gizi",
                "Prodi Farmasi",
                "Prodi Kebidanan"
            )
        )
    )   
);  
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Fakultas</th>
        <th>Jurusan</th>
        <th>Program Studi</th>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

And the result must be like this:
[image]

What should I do to make a table like this? I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
for($baris = 0 ; $baris < 2 ; $baris++ ) {
    echo $ub[$baris][0] ; $baris++;} ?>
    </th>
    <th>
    <?php 
    for($barisa = 0 ; $barisa < 2 ; $barisa++ ) {
        echo $ub[$barisa+1][1];
        $barisa++;
    }
    ?>
    </th>
    <th>
    <?php 
    for($barisb = 0 ; $barisb < 4 ; $barisb++ ) {
        echo $ub[$barisb+1][2] ;
        $barisb++;
    }
    ?>
    </th>
```

Thank you.

Comment: U need to study `rowspan`. Visit this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp

Comment: I mean not only the row span , I have problem using my code for looping .

Comment: Okay, then wait

Comment: `"Fakultas Ilmu Komputer",` should be one line down, which would properly put it in the next subarray.  Please correct your sample.

Comment: Please use the dynamic html format from https://tabletag.net/  and code for this by foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

You should alter your array slightly, so all the columns are on the same level like so:

```
  <?php
    $ub = array(
      "Fakultas Ilmu Komputer" => array(
                                    array(
                                        "Jurusan Teknik Informatika",
                                        array(
                                            "Prodi Teknik Informatika",
                                            "Prodi Teknik Komputer",
                                            "Prodi Magister Ilmu Komputer"
                                        )
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        "Jurusan Sistem Informasi",
                                        array(
                                            "Prodi Sistem Informasi",
                                            "Prodi Teknologi Informasi",
                                            "Prodi Pendidikan Teknologi Informasi"
                                        )
                                    )
                                ),
    "Fakultas Kedokteran" => array(
                                    array(
                                        "Jurusan Kedokteran",
                                        array(
                                            "Prodi Pendidikan Dokter"
                                        )
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        "Jurusan Keperawatan dan Gizi",
                                        array(
                                            "Prodi Ilmu Keperawatan",
                                            "Prodi Ilmu Gizi",
                                            "Prodi Farmasi",
                                            "Prodi Kebidanan"
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
  );

    ?>
```

After that, you'll have to keep track of all the 'inside rows' of the table and print the rows nested in the deepest loop. Like so:

```
<?php
foreach($ub as $fakultas => $jurusan) {
    $fakultasLine = true;

    // calculate inside rows per row
    $insideRows = 0;
    foreach($jurusan as $program) {
        foreach($program[1] as $studi) {
            $insideRows++;
        }
    }
    foreach($jurusan as $program) {
        $jurusanLine = true;
        foreach($program[1] as $studi) {
            echo '<tr>';
            if($fakultasLine) {
                echo '<td rowspan="' . $insideRows . '">' . $fakultas . '</td>';
                $fakultasLine = false;
            }
            if($jurusanLine) {
                echo '<td rowspan="' . count($program[1]) . '">' . $program[0] . '</td>';
                $jurusanLine = false;
            }
            echo '<td>' . $studi . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Your complete snippet would look a bit like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    th,
    td {
      padding: 5px;
      text-align: left;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <?php
    $ub = array(
      "Fakultas Ilmu Komputer" => array(
                                    array(
                                        "Jurusan Teknik Informatika",
                                        array(
                                            "Prodi Teknik Informatika",
                                            "Prodi Teknik Komputer",
                                            "Prodi Magister Ilmu Komputer"
                                        )
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        "Jurusan Sistem Informasi",
                                        array(
                                            "Prodi Sistem Informasi",
                                            "Prodi Teknologi Informasi",
                                            "Prodi Pendidikan Teknologi Informasi"
                                        )
                                    )
                                ),
    "Fakultas Kedokteran" => array(
                                    array(
                                        "Jurusan Kedokteran",
                                        array(
                                            "Prodi Pendidikan Dokter"
                                        )
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        "Jurusan Keperawatan dan Gizi",
                                        array(
                                            "Prodi Ilmu Keperawatan",
                                            "Prodi Ilmu Gizi",
                                            "Prodi Farmasi",
                                            "Prodi Kebidanan"
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
  );

    ?>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Fakultas</th>
        <th>Jurusan</th>
        <th>Program Studi</th>
      </tr>

<?php
foreach($ub as $fakultas => $jurusan) {
    $fakultasLine = true;

    // calculate inside rows per row
    $insideRows = 0;
    foreach($jurusan as $program) {
        foreach($program[1] as $studi) {
            $insideRows++;
        }
    }
    foreach($jurusan as $program) {
        $jurusanLine = true;
        foreach($program[1] as $studi) {
            echo '<tr>';
            if($fakultasLine) {
                echo '<td rowspan="' . $insideRows . '">' . $fakultas . '</td>';
                $fakultasLine = false;
            }
            if($jurusanLine) {
                echo '<td rowspan="' . count($program[1]) . '">' . $program[0] . '</td>';
                $jurusanLine = false;
            }
            echo '<td>' . $studi . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    }
}
?>


    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You showed some better techniques than what I was toying with.  You _could_ remove one for loop with `foreach($jurusan as $program){$insideRows+=count($program[1]);}`. Nice work regardless.

Comment: @mickmackusa I know... But this is a bit more readable. A recursive method could print this with even fewer lines of code used, but would not be as explanatory...

Answer (score -1):

All you want is this,

https://gist.github.com/hsharma-lsquared/94f10b8182e5ef3e8c465a2cd5159edb

Also let me know if it is working for you...